# how to get rid off browser's css for video tag

Tags: css, video

I have uploaded a video using html5 video tag and it seems to display like this:

[image]

I need to fix the video width with the upper and lower bar widths, but here I am getting problem with `user agent stylesheet`(browser's default css). How can I get rid off it?

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved by using `object-fit` property by making it to `cover` in a video tag.